# VK Python Получение плейлиста аудио

Tags: python, api, вконтакте, аудио

Есть вот такой бот который позволяет получить и послушать музыку из плейлиста любого пользователя у которого открыта музыка - https://t.me/Mixvk_bot

После вставки ссылки на пользователя он присылает треки которые можно скачать и послушать:

[image: Доказательство того что можно получить аудио]

При получении плейлиста в бота приходит около 180 аудио

Много искал как можно получить аудио, но нашел только информацию о том что c 2016 года нельзя получать информацию через вк апи. Но этот бот доказывает обратное, так как же я могу получить плейлист пользователя?

Этот скрипт мне нужен для создания такого же телеграмм бота, поэтому selenium не подходит

Comment: Он не использует api, это делается на запросах. Насколько помню, там аудио разбивается на куски, эти куски парсятся и складываются в одно

Comment: Пробовал спарсить ссылку `https://vk.com/audio?act=load_catalog_section`, ответ - `413 Request Entity Too Large`. Не понимаю как исправить эту ошибку